# Review Indicator Always Stuck at 0 For Weeks

Tags: support

For the past few weeks, my review queue on Stack Overflow has said "0 Posts." I have checked the review page at many different times, however, the number is always 0. I know that posts are being reviewed, because people's profile pictures are showing up to the right of the review queue.

Is there a setting on my account that stopped the reviews?

Thanks.

Edit: I do not believe that I have got a review ban, as I have revived no message.

[image: 0 in queue]

Comment: for me its the same. And I never got a review ban, so this cannot be the problem.

Comment: Yes, I have not received a review ban either (to the best of my knowledge, as I have not received any notifications)

Comment: to be fair, sometimes, every 1 or 2 days, I see a number next to "First Posts". Then I can do a few reviews - usually less than the number suggests - and then it's 0 again for at least the next few hours.

Comment: For me, it has been stuck at 0, and never moves up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those queues are often empty; many hover over them and hoover up all entries.

Comment: But it used to show numbers, and now it never does. Does this have anything to do with the number of posts/answers/comments I post?

Comment: for me, the number of posts doesn't follow a probability distribution that makes sense. most of the time it's zero. if it's not zero, it's usually >= 5. this means there must be some logic that enables or disables reviews so that we don't get the occassional "1" or "2".

Comment: We've been told several times that the system does not have any hidden bans. If it won't let you review, it grays things out. Probably this is another one of their caching effects.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Interestingly enough, right after posting this question on the meta site, the review page has started showing me open reviews.